# Given a function $f○g○h(x)$, where $f,g,h$ are bijective functions and $○$ is used to denote composition of functions . Then prove that $(f○g)○h(x)$

Tags: functions

Given a function $f○g○h(x)$, where $f,g,h$ are bijective functions and $○$ is used to denote composition of functions . Then prove that $(f○g)○h(x)=f○(g○h)(x)$.
I am not been able to quite solve it .

My approach goes like this :

> First of all, we know that if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are bijective functions then $f○g(x)$ is also a bijective functions. Now, considering $f○g(x)=\phi(x)$ so, $\phi○h(x)$ is also a bijective one . Now if $g○h(x)=\sigma(x)$ then $f○\sigma(x)$ is a bijective function as well. Now, how to prove that $f○\sigma(x)=\phi○h(x)$?

I can't seem to get it...

Comment: Both sides are equal to $f(g(h(x)))$. You don't even need bijectivity. Enough if the compositions are defined.

Comment: MathJax/LaTeX note: Use `\circ` for the composition symbol, that looks better.

Comment: @geetha290krm That's true ..but how to do it .. I mean how to prove that both sides will be equal to $f(g(h(x)))$?

Comment: @MartinR OK...Yeah...that might look better..Thank you...

Comment: That is how composition of functions is defined.

Comment: @geetha290krm Ok... then that is enough to prove it, right?